# Create search specification for Entity with Enum column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums, spring-data-jpa

I have this Entity with Enum column:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "status", length = 20)
private OnboardingTaskStatus status;
```

Where enum declaration looks like:

```
public enum OnboardingTaskStatus {
    NEW,
    IN_PROGRESS,
    DISABLED;
}
```

I tried to implement a Search Specification:

```
Specification<OnboardingTasks> spec = (root, query, cb) -> {
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    if (params.getTitle() != null) {
        predicates.add(cb.like(cb.lower(root.get("title")), "%" + params.getTitle().toLowerCase() + "%"));
    }
    if (params.getStatus() != null) {
        predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("status"), params.getStatus()));
    }
    return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
};
return onboardingTasksService
         .findAll(spec, pageable)
         .map(onboardingMapper::taskToTaskDTO);
```

I get an error:

> OnboardingTaskStatus.2769df0841; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant OnboardingTaskStatus.2769df0841] with root cause java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant OnboardingTaskStatus.2769df0841

Should I use a converter like

`@Convert(converter = OnboardingTaskStatus.class)`

as described here: [Mapping Enums Done Right With @Convert in JPA 2.1](https://dzone.com/articles/mapping-enums-done-right)

***Is there a better way to implement this?***

Comment: Is the `params.getStatus()` value type of `OnboardingTaskStatus`? Or is it the `String`?

Comment: It's a string value.

Comment: Then that's the problem. The types are mismatched. You should use the `OnboardingTaskStatus`. Hibernate does the conversion internally

Comment: If it is a String then the error message would mention the String value like so ```java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [NEW] did not match expected type [OnboardingTaskStatus (n/a)]```
May be there is not only the enum ```OnboardingTaskStatus``` but also a class with the same name?

Comment: Can you try to use `params.getStatus().name()` instead ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing what `params.getStatus()` is, so it's pretty hard to help you. From what the exception is saying, it comes to mind that this is returning an object that is not of the enum type `OnboardingTaskStatus`.